# Having a single website behind 2 domains

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, google-search

I have a website `www.mywebsite.com`. Recently I created a brand for my business, lets say it's called MyNewBrand.

I'm thinking of acquiring domain name `www.mynewbrand.com` and create a 301 redirect to `www.mywebsite.com`. From other posts I understand this should not affect search engine ranking at all (I'm aiming only for Google search engine).

However, if I do it:

- Will `mynewbrand.com` appear in search results if my users search for the brand name? Which of my domains will Google pick?
- If people create external links (blog posts, etc) to `mynewbrand.com`, will Google consider them as links to `mywebsite.com`?
- Should I 301 redirect only to the root? Example: I'm thinking how should I approach the situation where one of my users remembers `page1.html` and accesses: 
  `www.mynewbrand.com/page1.html`. Should I redirect to `www.mywebsite.com` or to `www.mywebsite.com/page1.html`?

What are the best approaches/practices to do this?

Comment: We get this question A LOT! Adding another domain name to your site will do absolutely nothing for you. Period. You would be wasting your time and money. Now if you were to move your existing site to the new domain, that would be something entirely different. But you would have work to do not only in moving the site, but also in branding the site. We can help with that. What you are proposing will not work. There is no benefit. Sorry. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closetnoc pretty much sums this up in comments... no benefit.

To answer your specific questions:

> I understand this should not affect search engine ranking at all

Correct. However, if `mynewbrand.com` was already an established domain/website that was already attracting significant traffic then you could benefit (if the subject matter of the original domain was similar). But for new domains with no history then no benefit.

> Will mynewbrand.com appear in search results if my users search for the brand name?

No.

> Which of my domains will google pick?

The target of the redirect. ie. `www.mywebsite.com`

> If people create external links (blog posts, etc) to mynewbrand.com, will google consider them as links to mywebsite.com?

Yes - sort of. Google reportedly does not pass 100% PR through redirects, so it's not quite as good as a direct link to `mywebsite.com`.

But... how would people find `mynewbrand.com` to begin with in order to link to it? You are redirecting users to `www.mywebsite.com`.

> Should I 301 redirect only to the root?

No. It's never a good idea to bulk redirect to the root. For search engines and users. Google is likely to see it as a soft-404 and ignore it. Whilst it just confuses users - who are then more likely to "bounce". (But again, how would `mynewbrand.com` be found anyway?)

---

The only benefit I can think of is in marketing material. Publish the *shorter* `mynewbrand.com` which redirects to the real/longer URL on your website.

Comment: Absolute perfection! Cheers!!

Comment: ok, thanks guys for the answers. it really helped me